# How do multiple addEventListener work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

There are two scripts in a document:

```javascript
// my_script.js goes first
document.onclick = function() {
    alert("document clicked");
};

// other_script.js comes after
// this overrides the onclick of my script,
// and alert will NOT be fired
document.onclick = function() {
    return false;
};
```

To make sure my `click` event does not get overridden by other script, I switched to `addEventListener`.

```javascript
// my_script.js goes first
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("document clicked");
}, false);

// other_script.js comes after
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    return false;
}, false);
```

Now I got another question. Since `return false` in the second code is defined after `alert`, how come it does not prevent alert from being called?

What if I want my script to get total control of click event (like `return false` all the time disregarding events defined in other scripts)?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> What if I want my script to get total control of click event (like return false all the time disregarding events defined in other scripts)?

If you can register your handler first, before they do, you can do that, provided the browser you're using correctly implements DOM3 events (which it probably does unless it's IE8 or earlier).

There are (at least) four things involved here:

1. Preventing the default.
2. Stopping propagation to ancestor elements.
3. Stopping other handlers on the *same* element from being called.
4. The order in which handlers are called.

In order:

### 1. Preventing the default

This is what `return false` from a DOM0 handler does. (Details: [*The Story on Return False*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html).) The equivalent in DOM2 and DOM3 is [`preventDefault`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Preventing the default may not be all that relevant to what you're doing, but since you were using `return false` in your DOM0 handler, and that prevents the default, I'm including it here for completeness.

### 2. Stopping propagation to ancestor elements

DOM0 handlers have no way to do this. DOM2 ones do, via [`stopPropagation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-stopPropagation):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

But `stopPropagation` doesn't stop other handlers on that same element getting called. From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-stopPropagation):

> The `stopPropagation` method is used prevent further propagation of an event during event flow. If this method is called by any `EventListener` the event will cease propagating through the tree. **The event will complete dispatch to all listeners on the current `EventTarget` before event flow stops.**

*(My emphasis.)*

### 3. Stopping other handlers on the *same* element from being called

Naturally, this didn't come up for DOM0, because there couldn't *be* other handlers for the same event on the same element. :-)

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to do this in DOM2, but DOM3 gives us [`stopImmediatePropagation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-stopImmediatePropagation):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, false);
```

Some libraries offer this feature (even on non-DOM3 systems like IE8) for handlers hooked up via the library, see below.

### 4. The order in which handlers are called

Again, not something that related to DOM0, because there couldn't be other handlers.

In DOM2, the specification *explicitly* says that the order in which the handlers attached to an element are called is not guaranteed; but DOM3 changes that, saying that handlers are called in the order in which they're registered.

First, from DOM2 [Section 1.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-basic-h3):

> Although all `EventListeners` on the `EventTarget` are guaranteed to be triggered by any event which is received by that `EventTarget`, no specification is made as to the order in which they will receive the event with regards to the other `EventListeners` on the `EventTarget`.

But this is superceded by DOM3 [Section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-phase):

> Next, the implementation must determine the current target's candidate event listeners. This must be the list of all event listeners that have been registered on the current target **in their order of registration**.

*(My emphasis.)*

Some libraries guarantee the order, provided you hook up the events with the library.

It's also worth noting that in Microsoft's predecessor to DOM2 (e.g., `attachEvent`), it was the opposite of DOM3's order: The handlers were called in *reverse* order of registration.

---

So taking #3 and #4 together, if you can register your handler first, it will get called first, and you can use `stopImmediatePropagation` to prevent other handlers getting called. Provided the browser implements DOM3 correctly.

---

All of this (including the fact that IE8 and earlier don't even implement DOM2 events, much less DOM3) is one reason people use libraries like jQuery, some of which do guarantee the order (as long as everything is hooking up their handlers via the library in question) and offer ways to stop even other handlers on the same element getting called. (With jQuery, for instance, the order is the order in which they were attached, and you can use `stopImmediatePropagation` to stop calls to other handlers. But I'm not trying to sell jQuery here, just explaining that some libs offer more functionality than the basic DOM stuff.)

Comment: well, I have actually tried that (`preventDefault`, and also `stopPropagation`) before posting. alert still gets called.

Comment: I wrapped the last block of code (addEventListener ... return false) in a setTimeout (3000), this should make sure it gets added after alert(), however, alert still gets called.

Comment: @user1643156: Again: The order in which the handlers is called is not guaranteed. Also, separately, as far as I'm aware there's no way via DOM2 to stop other handlers on the same element getting called (`stopPropagation` stops the event going to *ancestor* elements).

Comment: I changed alert to console.log. I kept clicking on the page, tried to get a random exception that `return fasle` gets called first since you quoted `not guaranteed` (I understood this as random), but with luck, console.log always gets called first.

Comment: @user1643156: I rewrote the answer, because at first I thought you were just trying to prevent the default. Also, I'd forgotten (sorry!) that the DOM3 events spec improves things markedly, including making what you want to do possible.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder, `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` works. But it has to be defined **before** any other event listeners. and the execution order of handlers is indeed from top to bottom, not much as you quoted `not guaranteed`, at least in my test. Thank you for the detailed information.

Comment: @user1643156: See my comment above: That was DOM2. I remembered DOM3 *does* guarantee it, and edited accordingly. :-)

Comment: Seems that DOM spec now moved to WHATWG https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-stopimmediatepropagation so this might evolve again along time

Comment: Note that *in practice* the order of handlers being called should be considered random. Some day in the future we may start to pretend that all UAs correctly follow DOM3.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen - I'm curious, what vaguely-modern UA doesn't follow DOM3+ order?

Comment: I'm not sure about the status of all vaguely-modern UAs. I was just pointing out that the order may not follow DOM3 and must be considered while designing any system using DOM events. For example, even Wikipedia only has collected info about DOM2 compatibility: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_engines_(DOM_support)#Events - however, https://caniuse.com/?search=stopImmediatePropagation claims good support for `stopImmediatePropagation()` which probably means those browsers implement the correct order.

Comment: As far as I know, the UI Events of DOM3 is still working draft so depending on it is risky.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen - Unless you can point to something that actually does it wrong, frankly I don't think that warning is at all useful here in 2020. DOM3 events was 2003 (now superceded by https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/). Even IE9 handled the order correctly if you used `addEventListener` (rather than `attachEvent`). (I was sure about IE11, but had to test it on IE9 to be sure.) Everything aside from IE had been doing it correctly for years even before this answer was posted in 2013. It's not going to change.

Comment: My point is that if you want to refer any specs, all pointers should go to WHATWG. W3C has failed to get any DOM specification to define Events out of "Working Draft" status since DOM2 in 2003. According to W3C rules, "Working Draft" specs should not be used in production. Another alternative is to declare that the working draft rules listed in the answer *appear* to work with real world user agents in year 2020. See https://www.w3.org/2004/02/Process-20040205/tr.html#maturity-levels for details.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen - There's what the W3C *says*, and the reality on the ground. But I have mostly switched over to WHAT-WG specs now, the links above notwithstanding. Do you happen to have the relevant link to hand?

Comment: I would link to https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-stopimmediatepropagation because W3C still has all specs mentioning that as Working Draft only. And the event dispatch has documentation at https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-dispatch which is the part you want to read if you care about modern HTML5 compliant browsers only.