# Do event attributes always fire before event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, event-handling, dom-events

I set two listeners for a form submission. One is specified in the `onsubmit` attribute, and the other was specified by using an `event listener`.

Based on my tests, the one specified in the attribute is always firing first. is this always going to be the case? Will event attributes **always** fire first? Or are there cases where this does not occur?

```js
function attribute(e) {
  console.log('Attribute');
  e.preventDefault();
}

function listener(e) {
  console.log('Listener');
  e.preventDefault();
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', listener);
```

```html
<form onsubmit="attribute(event)">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I recognize that [using event attributes should be "avoided"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes), and this is more a matter of understanding than anything.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that. Rather add all the listeners with `addEventListener`, they (the same type of events) are guaranteed to fire in the order of the definition.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. The reason this question even came up is because I have a 3rd party form validation plugin that is always being attached as soon as the JS is available to the page in a vendor bundle. There is nothing I can do to change it's location. Due to app architecture, my JS code is loaded after the vendor bundle. Therefore, the validators JS is always firing before my code :( . Although I won't be going the route of adding an event attribute, I'm still curious as to if this is always the case.

Comment: `onclick` is called before `.addEventListener("click")`. Could not locate details of expected result at specification, though appears to take precedence similar to `style` attribute at element

Comment: @KevBot See [Default action](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html#link3) _"`<A HREF="somewhere.html" onClick="doSomething()">`
In the case of a click on a link, the event handler must be executed first. After all, when the default action takes place —new page is loaded— the old page, including the event handler, is removed from browser memory. Therefore if the onclick event handler is to be executed at all, it must be done before the default action."_

Comment: [The specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#sync-async) says: "_Events which are synchronous ("sync events") are treated as if they are in a virtual queue in a first-in-first-out model_". An element must exist, before an event can be attached. This means, that an attribute event was pushed to the queue before JS can create its event. Things get more complex if the third-party script uses event delegation. You could try to remove the third-party listener, and re-attach it after you've attached your own (if you can get a reference to the third-party's handler function, ofcourse).

Answer (score 0):

I would assume in your case they fire first because the attributes tag gets processed first, but there's no guarantee this will always be the case for all browsers. Also, even in the case of just calling addEventListener() the ordering is not guaranteed before DOM 3. However, on DOM 3 event listeners will execute in the same order that they were registered. See the accepted answer here: [How do multiple addEventListener work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273635/how-do-multiple-addeventlistener-work-in-javascript)

To guarantee that the event listener will be called before the onclick, you can implement something like the following. This example, based on your snippet, changes the ordering of the calls so that you can put any arbitrary code before the attribute defined event.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function attribute(e) {
  console.log('Attribute');
  e.preventDefault();
}

function listener(e) {
  console.log('Listener');
  e.preventDefault();
}
window.onload = function() { 
     var form = document.querySelector('form');
     var f = form.onsubmit; 
     form.onsubmit = null;
     form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {listener(e); f(e);});
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form onsubmit="attribute(event)">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: The question is: "Will event attributes __always__ fire first?" Just testing a single case with one browser hardly answers the question.

Comment: This example will work in whichever browser. I just didn't test it., It will always change the ordering and fire the listener function before the attributes one. KevBot explained why he wants to know this, and it's because he's using a third-party library that adds events on attributes, and they fire before the events he adds. While the attributes could take precedence over listeners or not in a specific browser, the code I posted will work always regardless and will fire the desired events before the ones stated in the attributes. I'll try to make the answer clearer. Thanks.

Comment: How you can be sure your code would act in the same way in any browser? Even if the standard would clearly state that this is how the event firing should be ordered, you can't be sure all implementations really do it that way.  Browsers do weird things, especially IE. Also, I've understood, that _OP_ considers to add an inline event handler, since the third-party plugin adds its own event using `addEventListener`, and OP wants to fire their own listener before this plug-in-listener.

Comment: The OP states "my JS code is loaded after the vendor bundle", so it would be possible to change the ordering. Please check this snippet, I'm explicitly changing the ordering:

Comment: sorry, this snippet: var form = document.querySelector('form');
     var f = form.onsubmit; 
     form.onsubmit = null;
     form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {listener(e); f(e);});

Comment: Mmmmhh, I might have understood the problem backwards, and the OP might want to fire his function before a function previously added with addEventListener(). If that's the case, and the browser doesn't support DOM3 events  (in which case calling addEventListener() first would be the solution), then things are not so easy. –