# pdf.js add delay between page change

Tags: jquery, pdf, pdf.js

I'm using PDF.js for rendering my PDFs. 
I need to create a delay of 10 seconds between each page change event.
I have tried adding below event listener on my page, but this triggers after the default page change listener.

```
document.addEventListener("pagechange", function (e) {
            //my custom code here
});
```

It would be great to have some sample code or pseudo code for it.

Comment: What do you want / need to happen during that ten seconds? Do you want a user to stay on each page for at least ten seconds (prevent scrolling / changing page) or something different?

Comment: I need the user to stay on the same page for atleast 10 seconds and to prevent changing the page.

Comment: Crosspost of https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/8325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prevent a user from scrolling off a page if you want to rely on `scrollIntoView`.

That function tries to scroll a given element into the viewport.

```
/* I did not post the complete implementation here to avoid plain copy       *
 * and paste and to allow for own (and better) implemantations - if          *
 * someone prefers to see the working implementation, I might edit the post. */
```

#### Locking Page using scrollIntoView

So the question is: **what** element would you like to be scrolled to? The PDF.js has an element named viewer - it has that many children as the loaded PDF has pages.
The third child holds the third page of the PDF for example.

Next question: **when** do you want to scroll it into view? That looks a little bit harder. We can get the top position of an element from it's `DOMRect` by running `getClientRects()` on that element. If the top is larger than the viewports top border, we scrolled out.

For the bottom it's somewhat the same: the viewable part of the element (regarding height) is it's height minus the hidden part (that is outside of the viewport's top). If height - hiddenPart < heightOfTheViewport, we scrolled out at the bottom.

Assuming an element stored in `pc` (the page container), taking both of the above together you'd have:

```
function lockToPage() { 
  var rect = pc.getClientRects()[0];
  var offsetNav = vc.offsetTop;
  if (rect.y > offsetNav) { pc.scrollIntoView(true); }
  if (rect.height + rect.y - window.innerHeight < 0) {    pc.scrollIntoView(false); }
}
```

The `vc` is the view container which in turn holds all page containers - it's offset is taken into account as (in PDF.js) we might have a navigation bar visible.

The way the page is locked here is not very nice, as trying to scroll beyond the element makes the page vibrating.

Ignoring this glitch, how will we know **what page** (element) to lock to? 
Well, that's trivial as we have `PDFViewerApplication.page` for the page and 
`vc.children[pageIndex]` for our page container. All we have to do from there on is listening to a `pagechange` to update the current page.

So here is how we could put all that **locking** together:

```
function initLocker() {
  vc = document.getElementById("viewerContainer");
  pc = document.getElementById("page1").offsetParent;
  lockToPage();
  vc.addEventListener("scroll", lockToPage);
}
```

**Releasing** such a lock would be performed by removing the event listener from `vc`; but when should that be done? Well, ten seconds after ... after pagechange? Nope. As some pages could take their time to render, we'd better wait for the page to finish rendering, thus listening to `pagerendered`.

Small things we'd like to add is preventing the user from skipping pages and preventing user interaction before we have finished our setup.

Now we have all we need, I guess - taking our PDF.js source (viewer.html), we can add our code *before* the other JS includes to make sure our event listeners will be attached first, see [SO on multiple event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16273678/7763696)